py is not linked with latest python version
Regarding the answer py by default, i.e. without options, should use latest Python installed on system. But for some reason I have the following on my Windows 11:
$ py --version
Python 3.8.10

$ python3 --version
Python 3.12.2

How can this be explained? And how to link py with latest python version?
Unfortunately I don't remember how I did install them.

On Windows, the py launcher is a utility that allows you to specify which version of Python you want to run. When you run py --version it will display the version of the default Python interpreter registered with the py launcher and it seems it isn't the latest version installed on your system. You can reconfigure it as you want.
You can check installed Python versions using this command:
py -0p

and you can change the default Python version for py using this command:
py -3.12 --default


Interesting moment that article you mentioned says "If you use just -2 or -3 as the version switch, Python will launch the most recent version of Python 2.x or Python 3.x, as indicated.", but in my case py -3 --version returns Python 3.8.10 instead Python 3.12.2

py -3.12 --default doesn't work for me. unknown option --default Solution that works is here.
